# Find the target device for installed PCI devices

Tags: ubuntu, udev, pci

`enter code here`I would like to find idproduct, idvendor and serial number of devices that installed another device since I will write udev rules.

```
lspci -nn
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:10e5] (rev a1)
00:03.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:10e6] (rev a1)
01:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X111SL PCIe-to-PCI Reversible Bridge [12d8:e111] (rev 02)
02:04.0 Multimedia video controller [0400]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6810] (rev 10)
02:04.1 Multimedia video controller [0400]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6811] (rev 10)
02:04.2 Multimedia video controller [0400]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6812] (rev 10)
02:04.3 Multimedia video controller [0400]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6813] (rev 10)
02:04.4 Multimedia controller [0480]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6814] (rev 10)
02:04.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6815] (rev 10)
02:04.6 Multimedia controller [0480]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6816] (rev 10)
02:04.7 Multimedia controller [0480]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6817] (rev 10)
02:05.0 Multimedia video controller [0400]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6810] (rev 10)
02:05.1 Multimedia video controller [0400]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6811] (rev 10)
02:05.2 Multimedia video controller [0400]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6812] (rev 10)
02:05.3 Multimedia video controller [0400]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6813] (rev 10)
02:05.4 Multimedia controller [0480]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6814] (rev 10)
02:05.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6815] (rev 10)
02:05.6 Multimedia controller [0480]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6816] (rev 10)
02:05.7 Multimedia controller [0480]: Intersil Techwell TW6816 multimedia video controller [1797:6817] (rev 10)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Device [1af2:a001]
```

AND

```
udevadm info -q all -a -n /dev/video3


Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/10003000.pcie-controller/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0/video4linux/video3':
    KERNEL=="video3"
    SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{dev_debug}=="0"
    ATTR{index}=="0"
    ATTR{name}=="SDL H.264 Codec (V4L)"

  looking at parent device '/devices/10003000.pcie-controller/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:03:00.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="c353"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0xff0000"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{device}=="0xa001"
    ATTRS{devspec}==""
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="388"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-5"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="3f"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0xa001"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1af2"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1af2"

  looking at parent device '/devices/10003000.pcie-controller/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:03.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="pcieport"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x060400"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x10e6"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="388"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-5"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="3f"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x0000"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x10de"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x10de"

  looking at parent device '/devices/10003000.pcie-controller/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/10003000.pcie-controller':
    KERNELS=="10003000.pcie-controller"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="tegra-pcie"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
```

Comment: Didn't you already ask that on the superuser stackexchange? As I wrote there: There is no standard "serial number" for PCI devices. For your particular PCI card with 8 video cameras, if that's what it is, you need to give us details. Use `udevadm` to find out all the kernel knows about your `/dev/video*` devices.

Comment: please check my question again, I add something

Comment: Is the `c353` a custom kernel driver? I can't find it in my kernel source (but it's not the newest). Is the source code for this driver available? Because from the available parameters, it looks like the information just isn't there, which can only be fixed by modifying the kernel driver and making it supply this information to `udev`.

Comment: I use Nvidia Jetson TX2 and it is possible that c353 is a custom kernel which is provided by JetPack. However, I am not sure.
The source code of the driver is not available.

Comment: Then you probably need to complain to whoever wrote the driver...